# soapaction header is not passing through

Tags: header, traefik

I have a very simple definition in traefik.toml file.  The backend is a service that echoes back the header passed through.

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.test]
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "test"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.test.routes]
      [frontends.test.routes.route0]
        rule = "Host:localhost;PathPrefixStrip:/test"

[backends]
  [backends.test]
    [backends.test.servers]
      [backends.test.servers.server0]
        url = "http://localhost:8000"
        weight = 1
```

I can pass any http header from the client to the backend and it is echoed back as implemented in the backend service.  However I cannot pass `soapaction` header.  Traefik does not return any response till it times out.  Nothing in the log that indicates an issue.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that Traefik rewrites headers canonically as they should be case-insensitive (see https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/466).
Could you check that on your backend server ?

Comment: The backend server accepts case-insensitive "soapaction" header.  But traefik is not sending this particular header at all.  I checked with any header and all passes through except the literal header "soapaction".  It is as-if somewhere it is coded not to pass this header but I couldn't find any reference in traefik code.